# Having trouble copying JArray to ObservableCollection

Tags: json.net, observablecollection

So I feel like I'm really close, just missing a bit of glue to make the magic work.

Consider a code class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get;  set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "payee")]
    public string Payee { get;  set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "amount")]
    public double Amount { get;  set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
    public string Category { get;  set; }
}

private ObservableCollection<Transaction> items;
private JArray result;
```

and this JSON response from App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync

```
[
    {
        "date": "2014-09-26T00:00:00Z",
        "payee": "Expensive Restaurant",
        "amount": -199,
        "category": "Dining",
    }
]
```

I've verified that the JArray object returned is correctly parsed and populated.  I want to get the data into an ObservableCollection.

I've tried various incantations of that, with the simplest being:

```
items = result;
```

which errors with

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Transaction>'
```

or:

```
items = new ObservableCollection<Transaction> (result);
```

which errors with:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Transaction>'
```

I've read plenty of samples that make it seem like this should be super-easy, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This does what I want and works, but it seems I'm defeating the purpose of some built-in deserialization functionality of the JSON.NET classes:

```
            foreach (JObject jObject in result)
            {
                Transaction trans = new Transaction();
                trans.Date = (DateTime)jObject["date"];
                trans.Payee = (string)jObject["payee"];
                trans.Amount = (double)jObject["amount"];
                trans.Category = (string)jObject["category"];
                items.Add(trans);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a `JArray` in `result` and you want to convert it to an `ObservableCollection<Transaction>` you can do it like this:

```
items = result.ToObject<ObservableCollection<Transaction>>();
```

**Demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/saQmas

Comment: Yep!  That feels like the variation I never tried. :)